# Aditional properties not allowed SPFX webpart error

Tags: spfx, spfx-webparts

I'm getting this error when I use gulp serve

> Blockquote
>   Error: #/localizedResources (A set of localized resources, to be d...)
>          Additional properties not allowed: v3WebPartStrings
>   Error: #/bundles (A list of bundle definitions. Bundle ...)
>          Additional properties not allowed: v3-web-part

I'm a newbie to this so in need of advice as to what to investigate to try and fix problem.

Comment: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/deep-dive-into-sharepoint-framework-spfx-webpart-configuration-part-1/

Comment: thanks. going through the code with a fine tooth comb to find where the error is